# How to generate NLog.config with log level dependent on the solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, logging, msbuild, nlog

What's a good / typical strategy for generating / configuring a [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) configuration file (NLog.config) with the log level dependent on the solution configuration (e.g. Debug vs. Release)? Is there any built in NLog support for this, or is something like [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I've moved the NLog configuration into web.config and app.config sections.  Assuming then that you have a release dependent config deployment that's all there is to it.

```
<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
```